# How to implement a four layer dropdown list with mutual dependent lists?

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, livecycle

Good day. Thanks for your help thus far. Please, I am trying to create a four layer dependent drop down in adobe life cycle using JavaScript on the xml source and I’m not too familiar with either language. I got a sample script which can achieve only two layers dependent dropdown thus

```
// This script object controls the interaction between the court and PO Drop-down lists.
// The array contains the court and the corresponding PO.

var myCourts = new Array(new Array (), new Array (), new Array (), new Array ()); 
// Create a two-dimensional array.
// For each court, add a 'new Array(number of PO +1)'.

// Define the court and the corresponding PO.
// The array syntax is arrayName[index][index].
// The first index number represents the court,
// the second index number is the actual data value.

myCourts[0][0] = " ";       // The first items in the Drop-dowm Lists should be blank.
myCourts[0][1] = " ";
myCourts[1][0] = "Barnstable";  // The first data value is the court name,
myCourts[1][1] = "";    
myCourts[1][2] = "Smith";      // the rest are PO names.
myCourts[1][3] = "Brown";


myCourts[2][0] = "Berkshire";
myCourts[2][1] = "";
myCourts[2][2] = "Green";
myCourts[2][3] = "Red";


myCourts[3][0] = "Bristol";
myCourts[3][1] = "";
myCourts[3][2] = "Long";
myCourts[3][3] = "Short";



// This function will populate the court Drop-down List.
// This function is called from the initialize event of the court Drop-down List.

function getCourts(dropdownField)
{
   dropdownField.clearItems();
   for (var i=0; i &lt; myCourts.length; i++)
      dropdownField.addItem(myCourts[i][0]);
}
```

So I modified it thus for four layers based on my knowledge of matrices and basic programming

```
var myCourts = new Array(new Array (new Array (new Array (), new Array (),new Array (), new Array () )), new Array (new Array (new Array (), new Array (),new Array (), new Array () )),  new Array ());


myCourts[0][0][0][0] = " ";     // The first items in the Drop-dowm Lists should be blank.
myCourts[0][1][0][0] = " ";
myCourts[1][0][0][0] = "ANIMALS";   // The first data value is the court name,
myCourts[1][1][0][0] = "";  

myCourts[1][2][0][0] = "BIRDS";  
myCourts[1][2][1][0] = "";           // the rest are PO names. 

myCourts[1][2][2][0] = "FLYING BIRDS";
myCourts[1][2][2][1] = ""; 
myCourts[1][2][2][2] = "EAGLE"; 
myCourts[1][2][2][3] = "DOVE"; 

myCourts[1][2][3][0] = "WALKING BIRDS"; 
myCourts[1][2][3][1] = ""; 
myCourts[1][2][3][2] = "CHICKEN"; 


myCourts[1][2][4][0] = "JUMPING BIRDS"; 
myCourts[1][2][4][1] = ""; 
myCourts[1][2][4][2] = "OSTRICH"; 


/* End of first  */

myCourts[1][3][0][0] = "MAMMALS";
myCourts[1][3][1][0] = "";           // the rest are PO names. 

myCourts[1][3][2][0] = "WALKING MAMMALS";
myCourts[1][3][2][1] = ""; 
myCourts[1][3][2][2] = "MAN"; 
myCourts[1][3][2][3] = "APES"; 


myCourts[1][3][3][0] = "SWIMMING MAMMALS"; 
myCourts[1][3][3][1] = ""; 
myCourts[1][3][3][2] = "WHALES"; 


/* END OF LISTS IN ANIMALS  */


/* PLANTS  */

myCourts[2][0][0][0] = "PLANTS";    
myCourts[2][1][0][0] = "";  

myCourts[2][2][0][0] = "TREES";  
myCourts[2][2][1][0] = "";           // the rest are PO names. 

myCourts[2][2][2][0] = "TALL TREES";
myCourts[2][2][2][1] = ""; 
myCourts[2][2][2][2] = "IROKO"; 
myCourts[2][2][2][3] = "PALM TREE";

myCourts[2][2][3][0] = "SHORT TREES"; 
myCourts[2][2][3][1] = ""; 
myCourts[2][2][3][2] = "ORANGE"; 
myCourts[2][2][3][3] = "APPLE TREE"; 


/* End of first  */

myCourts[2][3][0][0] = "SHRUBS";
myCourts[2][3][1][0] = "";           // the rest are PO names. 

myCourts[2][3][2][0] = "WEEDS";
myCourts[2][3][2][1] = ""; 
myCourts[2][3][2][2] = "ELEPHANT GRASS"; 
myCourts[2][3][2][3] = "SISTOSOMA MARIJUANTUS"; 

myCourts[2][3][3][0] = "FLOWERS"; 
myCourts[2][3][3][1] = ""; 
myCourts[2][3][3][2] = "ROSE "; 
myCourts[2][3][3][3] = "PRIDE OF BARBARDOS"; 


/* END OF LISTS IN PLANTS  */



// This function will populate the court Drop-down List.
// This function is called from the initialize event of the court Drop-down List.

function getCourts(dropdownField)
{
   dropdownField.clearItems();
   for (var i=0; i &lt; myCourts.length; i++)
      dropdownField.addItem(myCourts[i][0][0][0]);
}
```

My code is not functioning properly because of the way I defined the "var mycourts arrays" on line 1 of my  code.
please I’ll be greatful if anyone can help me over this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please describe your problem more clearly. Does that (large) block of code that you've shown not work at all, or partially work, or do the wrong thing? Are you getting errors in the browser console? Or...?

Comment: Please explain what is not working, do you see error messages or else...? Also, consider a jsfiddle.

Comment: @peter_the_oak With jsfiddle you mean a runnable Code Snippet in the question? :)

Comment: @Austine, yes, there are several online tools that help you quickly design, draft, experiment, debug some JS/CSS/HTML code. Here are three examples: 1) [http://www.jsfiddle.net/](http://www.jsfiddle.net/), 2) [http://jsbin.com/](http://jsbin.com/), 3) [http://codepen.io/](http://codepen.io/). I recommend to use them, and if you ask questions, it will save time for all people if you prepare your code in such a tool. Often while preparing, you'll understand the solution yourself. BTW, such tools also exist for many other, "not-web" languages.

Comment: good day. please i reedited my questions earlier today. Please let me know if its clear enough. Thank you very much